# write client ip in iis 7.0 log over firewalls

Tags: iis-7, logging, isapi, clientip

I need a solution for IIS 7.0 which runs on windows server 2008 64bit to write my clients IP to IIS logs while the server is behind firewalls and proxies (Pass X-Forwarded-For header value).

I've tried to install the an ISAPI Filter written by Joe Pruitt. it works great on Windows Server 2003 32bit IIS 6.0, but seems to do nothing at all on windows server 2008 64bit IIS 7.0.

Did anyone try this ISAPI filter on this version of OS? or have another solution?

link to the Joe Pruitt's (from F5) ISAPI filter:
http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2009/08/19/x_forwarded_for_log_filter_for_windows_servers.aspx

best regards,

guy bertental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem - the ISAPI DLL had no read permissions for the application pool's identity.

Comment: Can you tell how did you solved the problem step by step? I'm having same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014816/cannot-get-user-ip-address-proxy-firewall-load-balancer