# Cannot get user IP address (proxy/firewall/load balancer)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ip-address, iis-7.5

I used code below to get client ip with asp.net before but after I moved to VDS this function begin returning only my subnet mask which is 178.18.198.1 or 178.18.198.2.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
Private Function GetIPAddress() As String
    Dim sIPAddress As String = Nothing
    sIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sIPAddress) Then
        sIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
    End If

    Return sIPAddress
End Function
```

**EDIT**

Found similar problem [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1175435.aspx):

> Have deployed many 2008 32 bit
>   standard web servers using the citrix
>   netscaler isapi (the netscaler being a
>   load balancer), in all cases the
>   client IP address is logged in the
>   standard IIS logs. On a new project I
>   was asked to deploy 2008 R2,
>   configured IIS 7.5 identically with
>   how I configured IIS 7.0 in the past,
>   this time however the client ip is
>   returning the load balancer address in
>   the logs. Here is the weird part, I
>   installed "advanced logging" and it is
>   showing the client IP address
>   properly, so the isapi is doing its
>   job. Have googled this one to death
>   and could use some advice.

I also found ISAPI Filter module but cannot make it work: [devcentral.f5.com/x_forwarded_for_log_filter_for_windows_servers](http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2009/08/19/x_forwarded_for_log_filter_for_windows_servers.aspx)

Comment: Figured out that HTTP_CLIENT_IP returns my right ip address but why this code is not working as previous??

Comment: A 3rd party module, written by one of F5’s architects
https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/x-forwarded-for-http-module-for-iis7-source-included#.UdrYQ6TD9mM

Comment: `IIS7/8: Logging the real client IP in the IIS hit logs`
https://blogs.iis.net/deanc/iis7-8-logging-the-real-client-ip-in-the-iis-hit-logs ***Options***: _Advanced Logging, ARR, F5 Module_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved by using HTTP_CLIENT_IP instead of REMOTE_ADDR in sourcecode files.

The problem about IIS Logs was solved by installing IIS Advanced Logging module as suggested [here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX125526). Also I got error "503: Service Unavailable" after installing Advanced Logging but solved this by granting read-write permissions to Everyone for Program Files\IIS folder and started failed application pools.

http://kb.parallels.com/6735

Another solution suggested [here](http://forums.iis.net/p/1175435/1982942.aspx#1982942) is:

> On the NetScaler under "load
>   balancing", "Services" then under the
>   advanced tab, under settings, check
>   the box for "Use Source IP" and
>   "Client IP" then in the Header field 
>   "CLIENT-IP"

Comment: http://kb.parallels.com/6735 redirect to http://kb.plesk.com/en/6735, and not found

Comment: Useful about ***Advanced Logging***
_1)_ https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging
_2)_ http://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/iis-and-x-forwarded-for-header
_3)_ https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
IP.Text = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

In C#. Does that work for you?

Comment: No it is returning same address: 178.18.198.2

Comment: This works fine for me, it seems more an infrastructure issue

Comment: Asked question at serverfault, hope the problem solves: http://serverfault.com/questions/270751/server-records-wrong-ips

Comment: Its due to the IIS Proxy, I have same issue, unfortunately Pleun, the ip header is changed at the IIS Proxy / Proxy level.

Comment: The same is `Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString()`