# How to get the user ip address (REMOTE_ADDR / HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR) on HTTPS and Load Balancing

Tags: https, ip-address, load-balancing

I need to get the ip address of the users of my website, because I need to present localized content according to country.

I have a load balancing server and because this I use the **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR** to get the ip address, its ok, but since I set the HTTPS for the entire site I cannot get the **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR** data, it returns empty, and only can get the **REMOTE_ADDR**, but this returns the Load Balancing Server ip address and not the user ip address.

How I can get the user's ip address when using load balancing and HTTPS?

I'm using ASP.NET 2.0

Comment: Tip for who gets here: don't rely the localization of your website on an geolocalization over IP information. Try instead to use some tools built for it, like [HTML5 Geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/) or the GPS of user's device (in case that your application works on smartphones).

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that [I'm having the exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914457/why-does-servervariableremote-addr-returns-the-server-ip). In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014816/cannot-get-user-ip-address-proxy-firewall-load-balancer) they suggest to use HTTP_CLIENT_IP. I haven't tested it myself, let me know if this works.