# What is the difference between HTTP_CLIENT_IP and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR?

Tags: http, proxy, header, ip-address

I understand that a header `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is set by proxy servers to identify the ip-address of the host that is making the HTTP request through the proxy. I've heard claims that the header `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` is set for similar purposes.

1. What is the difference between `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`?
2. Why would one have different values than the other?
3. Where can I find resources on the exact definition of these headers.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Neither of these headers are officially standardised. Therefore:

1. `What is the difference between HTTP_CLIENT_IP and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR?` - it is impossible to say. Different proxies may implement these, or may not. The implementations may vary from one proxy to the next, and they may not. A lack of a standard breeds question marks.
2. `Why would one have different values than the other?` - See point 1. However, from a purely practical point of view, the only reason I can see for these having different values is if more than one proxy was involved - the `X-Forwarded-For:` header might then contain a complete track of the forwarding chain, whereas the `Client-IP:` header would contain the actual client IP. This is pure speculation, however.
3. `Where can I find resources on the exact definition of these headers.` - You can't. See point 1.

There does seem to be [some kind of de-facto standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) regarding the `X-Forwarded-For:` header, but <strike>given that there is no RFC that defines it this cannot be relied upon</strike> see comment below.

As a side note, the `Client-IP:` header should by convention be `X-Client-IP:` since it is a 'user-defined' header.

Comment: It does seem to have an RFC now: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-petersson-forwarded-for-02.  Although still in draft it seems.

Comment: RFC 7239 is no more a draft: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7239 Seems the future standard to replace both `X-Forwarded-For`and `X-Client-IP`.

Comment: ***Useful*** _1)_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914457/why-does-servervariableremote-addr-returns-the-server-ip

_2) IIS7/8: Logging the real client IP in the IIS hit logs_ 
https://blogs.iis.net/deanc/iis7-8-logging-the-real-client-ip-in-the-iis-hit-logs

_3) Advanced Logging_
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging

_4)_ http://www.loadbalancer.org/blog/iis-and-x-forwarded-for-header
_5)_ https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85

Comment: Proposed standard is here from 2014: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7239