# Wrong client IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I'm getting client IP address from ASP.NET. But some client IP address received 127.0.0.1.
What is problem. How getting valid client ip address?

I'm using this code:

```
    public static string GetIP()
{
    string clientIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIp))
    {
        string[] forwardedIps = clientIp.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        clientIp = forwardedIps[forwardedIps.Length - 1];
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIp))
        clientIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientIp))
        clientIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    return clientIp.ToString();
}
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost address, I suppose that you are connecting to the page from the same computer on which it is hosted?

Comment: just a guess? but could be proxy issues. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445592/what-is-the-difference-between-http-client-ip-and-http-x-forwarded-for

Comment: sircapsolat, I think so. But I could not find how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is localhost, i.e. the same machine is making the request as is hosting it.

My guess is that what you are seeing is infact your own testing or debugging?

I'd consider Request.IsLocal() as a good way to find out.

Comment: attacking my server this IP. it's creating 100-200 session per second.