# PHP: Get REAL client IP if hosting with Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, ip-address

In the past I used

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Which would return the client's IP. I've recently started hosting my site with Heroku, and I found that the above code no longer returns the client IP.

Has anyone come across this? How would I use PHP to obtain the real IP address of the client if my site is hosted with Heroku?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445592/what-is-the-difference-between-http-client-ip-and-http-x-forwarded-for) might be helpful.