# Having Users IP Address Showing In My Email Form

Tags: php, html, forms, joomla

Hello I have created an email form but am very unfamiliar with how to code in a section that displays a users IP address in the email that is sent. Here is my code.

Comment: There is no code related to IP addresses in your question. What have you tried?

Comment: Not sure where to start. I've never worked with IP addresses in code before. I tried to google it but had no luck.

Comment: You want to include your IP address from the email server, or you want to put the recipient's IP address in the email body?

Comment: I would like to put the recipients ip address in the email body

Comment: IP does not uniquely identify a user, so its kind of useless

Comment: I want it in there though because I have always wanted to try it out. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be sure of the real IP of the person using your email form because they could be behind a proxy or VPN, but this is a way to get the best candidate IP address at the time of the visit ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646690/how-to-get-real-ip-from-visitor)):

```
function getUserIP() {
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $client;
    } else if(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $forward;
    } else {
        $ip = $remote;
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Then you can add the IP information to your email body with

```
$myMessage .= "Sent from IP: " . getUserIP() . ".";
```

Further reading: [What is the difference between HTTP_CLIENT_IP and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445592/what-is-the-difference-between-http-client-ip-and-http-x-forwarded-for)

Comment: Hi Drakes how would I go about adding that php code to this,

Comment: $myMessage = $myNameLabel .' '. $_POST["m_name".$unique_id].', '.
$myEmailLabel .' '. $_POST["m_email".$unique_id].', '.
date("r");

Comment: `$myMessage .=` (notice the dot) appends more text to `$myMessage`, so you can use the line supplied in my answer to add the IP info to end of your message.

Comment: Alternatively, `$myMessage = $myNameLabel .' '. $_POST["m_name".$unique_id].', '. $myEmailLabel .' '. $_POST["m_email".$unique_id].', '. date("r") . ', ' . getUserIP();`

Comment: @EndôFujimoto How did that work out for you?

Comment: Worked fantastic. Sorry mate for not replying. Really appreciate the help