# How to get client real ip from CDN

Tags: php

```
if ( getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') ) {
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
} else if( getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') ) {
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    $ipaddress = explode(",", $ipaddress);
    $ipaddress = $ipaddress[0];
} else if( getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED') ) {
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
} else if( getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR') ) {
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
} else if( getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED') ) {
    $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
} else if( getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') ) {
    $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
} else {
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
}
```

How do I get real ip from CDN? I try to google it, but there is no any post about this. anyone can help?

Comment: What does 'real IP from CDN' mean? Be detailed and specific.

Comment: The obvious question: What CDN? No universal answer. (What you have is wrong.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using with $_SERVER

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
```

Sometime getenv does not return the correct IP address, so we can use $_SERVER instead.

Comment: how aboiut getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')

Comment: both the function are same and for IP address we have $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']

Comment: @PramodPatil it depends entirely on what IP the poster actually wants which is not clear from the question at all.

Comment: @pvg You havent got the question please check again.If you have downvoted because of that please upvote.

Comment: No. It's a completely unclear question. The code shown tries to extract the 'original' by a cascade of comparisons, yours just picks one of the (several) nonstandards headers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445592/what-is-the-difference-between-http-client-ip-and-http-x-forwarded-for It's not equivalent and, again, it's not clear what the OP is asking. Both the question and answer are of poor quality.

Comment: Ok..Please downvote this as well for your satisfaction..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php

Comment: This isn't even valid PHP syntax!