# How to figure out if the request being made to the website is from original ip or being masked by anonymous proxy server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I am using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

but I want to know if the request being made is with the original ip of the requestee or begin masked by the anonymous proxy servers i.e. zenmate etc.

How to figure that out ?

Comment: Do you have a list of anonymous proxy servers to verify against? You can't always tell whether the request originates via a proxy from the request headers because these can be manipulated

Comment: As @MartinParkin states, it's not 100% reliable. There is `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` but I don't know how reliable it is.

Comment: @Steve I am using Zenmate but still this HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR comes null in the program why ?

Comment: Because not all proxies add that header - some may. As was said earlier I don't think there is a reliable way. The client_IP may work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445592/what-is-the-difference-between-http-client-ip-and-http-x-forwarded-for

Comment: You may want to do a for each on the `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables` keys and see exactly what Zenmate is passing - though that would probably only be applicable to Zenmate.