# Difference Between x-forwarded-for and client_ip in HTTP Log Files?

Tags: http, x-forwarded-for

For obtaining originating Client IP address,X-forwarded-for is usually used.But in http log file,I saw something like this example:
client_ip=1.1.1.1
x-forwarded-for=2.2.2.2
is there any difference between these two IP's?

Comment: Please refer to the following StackOverflow article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445592/what-is-the-difference-between-http-client-ip-and-http-x-forwarded-for

Answer (score 0):

Client IP is the IP of the request whereas X-Forwarded-For is an IP that has been set by someone in the header. Most common usage example is a reverse proxy:
Client IP is then the IP of the reverse proxy (e.g. localhost). Therefore a typical reverse proxy configuration would send X-Forwarded-For to the IP of the original address, so that you can identify where the request was originally coming from.

However, it is also possible for the requester to set X-Forwarded-For to any arbitrary IP. In some use cases this can help to bypass geo-restrictions (e.g. for IPTV). So requester from Country A (that is geo-restricted) sets X-Forwarded-For to IP from Country B (that is not restricted). IPTV delivers content assuming original requester is from country B.