# How to Get Client IP Address using Asp.Net C# - When our Project is Hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip, client, ip-address

i am working in asp.net c#, in that i need to get client IP Address to display the client IP.
i am hosting my project in IIS 7, using the static ip i can connect my application..

i have to fetch the client IP using the following code. but i can't get correct ip address..

every time i get this ip 192.168.1.18..

i use the following code

```
private void GetIP()
    {
       string userip = Request.UserHostAddress;
        if (Request.UserHostAddress != null)
        {
            Int64 macinfo = new Int64();
            string macsrc = macinfo.ToString("X");
            if (macsrc == "0")
            {
                if (userip == "127.0.0.1")
                {
                    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Message", "alert('Visited Localhost')", true);
                    lblIPAddress.Text = userip;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblIPAddress.Text = userip;
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

i am also using the following code also but it showing the hosted ip address like 192.168.1.5, where i am hosted my project in server..

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            //if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            if (ip.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Local IP Address Not Found!");
    }
```

i need the correct client ip address, any one help

Comment: This can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

try this :

> string IP = Request.UserHostAddress;

Answer (score 1):

It was answered a while ago but theres a similar question here
[How to Get IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907195/how-to-get-ip-address) which uses the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and REMOTE_ADDR request variables. We used this in a project recently and its been working fine

Comment: sir its working fine when you hosted in cloud, but when we hosted in our own server (which is IIS) its not working.. so that i need help sir..

Comment: We used this on our IIS server and it worked still works

Comment: sir i checked once again, its also shows like this 192.168.1.18

Comment: @Surya you could try reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914457/why-does-servervariableremote-addr-returns-the-server-ip they seem to have the same problem,

Comment: it shows 127.0.0.1 when i execute the project, but when i hosted it shows 192.168.1.18..