# How to get client's IP address on an Azure Web App developed in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have developed a web application that is deployed as a web app on Azure.

I need to get the client's IP address such that I can use a GeoIP API to get the country from which the client is connecting.

So here's my question, how can I get the client's IP address when they send a request to view the homepage? I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` won't work?

Comment: I tried System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; but it returns null so does ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]

Comment: You could check this list https://stackoverflow.com/a/6914521/2373249

Comment: what about `Request.UserHostAddress`?

Answer (score 10):

Try this (verified on an Azure Web App using ASP.NET Core 2.x):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using System.Net;

....

var connection = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>();
IPAddress clientIP = connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

Comment: IPv4 Address? I think it is not.

Comment: This works on .net core 3.1

Comment: This led me to what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in a filter with Azure and .NET6: -

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace MyProject.Filters
{
    public class CustomActionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var visitorIp = context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```