# Get client IP in Azure through MVC 5 controller

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I can't find a question or post specific to Azure for this, and I'm not sure what's different in the environment in Azure versus my testing environments that would cause this. 
I've tried a few methods to get this to work but I'm not coming right. Please note this **isn't** Webapi, so using the HttpRequestMessage, as far as I know, is not going to work either.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Method 1:**

```
string ipAddress = "";
IPHostEntry Host = default(IPHostEntry);
Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Environment.MachineName);
ipAddress = Host.AddressList.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).MapToIPv4().ToString();
```

**Method 2:**

```
string userIP = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userIP))
{
    userIP = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
return userIP;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the value transported in this header:

```
x-forwarded-for: "91.23.44.24:52623"
```

Note there's a source port number trailing the IP address, so parse accordingly.

Also, as [@NicoD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2907312/nicod) correctly points out, the header in question [may contain an array of proxy servers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) the request traversed. For example:

```
x-forwarded-for: "91.23.44.24:52623, 91.23.44.155"
```

> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> X-Forwarded-For: <client>, <proxy1>, <proxy2>
> ```

> `<client>` The client IP address

> `<proxy1>, <proxy2>` If a request goes through multiple proxies, the IP addresses of each successive proxy is listed. This means, the right-most IP address is the IP address of the most recent proxy and the left-most IP address is the IP address of the originating client.

What about that glaring port number you ask?

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239:

> #### 5.2.  Forwarded For

> [...] this parameter MAY instead contain an IP
> address (and, **potentially, a port number**).

All client requests are terminated in the frontend layer and proxied via Application Request Routing to your web worker (hosting the MVC5 application).

[image: App Service Application Request Routing]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it differently from how I tried above in my example of things I tried? Did I do something incorrectly there?

Comment: There is no client IP information available to your web worker's environment, so the traditional `Request.ServerVariables` won't work in App Service. You did nothing wrong, it just doesn't apply here.

Comment: There's also this way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46516146/4148708 - but i'm not sure how that translates to Full Framework ASP.NET. Checking the header yourself should be faster since you don't instantiate anything extra.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this because as you said, the port number is included and needs to be removed for the rest of the code to work -  which wasn't taken into account when the guys tested using the header method. I don't think they saw the output unfortunately.

Comment: Note that x-forwarded-for can contain multiple IP addresses if the request is chained by proxy servers : X-Forwarded-For: <client>, <proxy1>, <proxy2> . see [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)

Comment: Very good point, adding that in. There's apparently an RFC that's cool with the port number as well.